# Issue with sum 2 numeric

Tags: c#, linq

I face a issue when check null then sum 2 numeric

code example

```
classA obj = new classA{ a = 2, b = 3}

var x = obj.a??0 + obj.b??0

The result x was 2
```

Expected is 5

Please give me the reason why? And how to do the operation like this?

NOTE: I use linq to retrieve obj

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that you are missing parentheses:

```
var x = (obj.a??0) + (obj.b??0);
```

The parser treats your non-parenthesized expression as follows:

```
var x = obj.a ?? (0 + obj.b??0);
```

The portion where you add `obj.b` is evaluated only when `obj.a` is `null`. When `obj.a` has a non-null value, `obj.b` is ignored.